# Completing roads output of PostGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, openstreetmap, osm2pgsql

I converted the file I exported from OSM to PostGIS using osm2pgsql. I have opened the table's outputs to QGIS and I saw data are not complete compare to OSM editor view. Most of the roads are broken and out of align.

[image: Screenshot of broken and unaligned line]

How do I complete them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The planet_osm_roads table in POSTGIS is only designed for rendering at lower zoom levels.

For higher zoom levels, take the planet_osm_line table and filter for features with highway.

If you still don't see all roads: How did you get the data from OSM? The export function might skip ways that are not completely inside the view. You better use the Overpass API or Geofabrik regional extracts instead.

For the alignment issue: In QGIS, `Set CRS for Layer` for the postgis layer to EPSG:3857, since EPSG:900913 is not in the CRS database of QGIS.

Comment: I exported the data from OSM and use osm2pgsql to convert .osm to PostGIS database

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question? `Save As Image` should work.

Comment: I have added the screenshot.

Comment: Are you using a recent version of osm2pgsql? Older versions do not support current node numbers. Alternatively, you can use the QGIS Openstreetmap plugin, step 2 and 3 (You have already downloaded the raw data).

Comment: The map I need to work with is not common so there's no raw data in Geofabrik. My only choice is to use the whole country but this makes the system slow. Yes, I'm using the recent osm2pgsql. MY final output will be using OpenLayer for web mapping.

Comment: Okay the problem solved by using the data from Geofabrik but how ofter they update their OSM raw file in the Philippines? If we edit the data from OSM, how many days it will take before we get their version? Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: The download page http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/philippines.html notes that the data is from yesterday (as all other osm.pbf too).You can filter the data with osmconvert or osmfilter before adding to the database if that speeds up your work.

Comment: The problem is not related to using planet_osm_roads, the broken road geometry indicates that the features are there, but their geometry wasn't built correctly.

Answer (score 4):

What is occuring appears to be a [somewhat subtle bug](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/issues/151) with osm2pgsql where osm2pgsql requires id-sorted nodes, but the API does not guarantee that.

The easiest solution is to import with `--slim --drop`. The `--slim` flag causes osm2pgsql to use the database instead of memory for temporary storage, which gives an option for coping with unordered files. The `--drop` flag causes the temporary information to be dropped from the database when osm2pgsql is finished.

Another option would be to use osmosis and `--sort` the XML file, but I don't suggest this as it's more complicated and requires installing osmosis.

Comment: Strangely, it worked for me with `osm2pgsql --create --database bboxdb --username osmuser --prefix planet -s --cache 3000 -S D:\Karten\OpenStreetMap\osm2pgsql\extended.style --hstore D:\Karten\osm\osm2pgsql\map.osm` without loosing nodes. Maybe I just did not catch the same bbox as the asker.

Comment: ``-s`` is short for ``--slim``. It is also worth noting that although the API provides no guarantee that the output is id-sorted, depending on details of the configuration, it may be.

Answer (score -1):

osm2pgsql imports OSM data in Mercator EPSG:900913. Ensure your Geometry Column in PostGis is set to EPSG:900913 using [UpdateGeometrySRID](http://postgis.net/docs/UpdateGeometrySRID.html)

You may need to install the EPSG:900913 Proj in your PostGis database using the instructions [here!](http://rahulteni.blogspot.com/2010/05/adding-900913-projection-to.html)

Ensure your QGis Layer Projection matches as well.

If you want to Reproject to EPSG:4326 (WGS84) Then you can do the following in PostGres

```
 ALTER TABLE mytable 
   ALTER COLUMN geom 
   TYPE Geometry(Point, 4326) 
   USING ST_Transform(geom, 4326);
```

Comment: Is it safe to alter even my final result will be posted in web using OpenLayer?

Comment: I'm sorry its a confusion for me. What is the purpose of updating geometry SRID to EPSG:900913 if I will reproject it again EPSG:4326 as my choice for web mapping display? It will display the same result? Right?

Comment: You do not update the Geometry to 900913, it probably already is if you used osm2pgsql. What projection is the geometery is in the database? If you did not change it, then it is probably 900913. You can use reprojection, but we choose not to as OSM and our data is all in 900913. IS your QGIS doing the proper reprojection to WGS84? If the data is stored in 900913, then QGIS has to have that set on the layer to display the layer properly. You can turn on automatic on the fly reprojection in QGis in the Settings

Comment: If you do not have thh 900913 SRID in your PostGIS database, you will have to install it as per the link I gave you

Comment: I'm working with lines and roads I have switched my projection for vector layer to 900913. It added some lines but the alignment and roads are not presented as perfect as OSM is.

Comment: If you load the postgis data into QGIS, with an Openstreetmap background via Openlayers plugin, does it get better if you set the Postgis layer CRS to EPSG:3857 using `Set CRS for Layer`?